# How to make the width of a left sidebar menu manually resizable by the user?

Tags: html, css

I built a menu using this method: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push

I need to make it manually resizable by the user.

I added `resize: horizontal;` to the `menu` class in CSS, but:

- the user can only grab the panel at the very bottom right of the menu, which is very small, it would be better if the mouse could catch and drag the menu border on any place of its vertical right border
- the animation to open the menu is now polluting the manual resize, it's like we have to pull very strong on the menu to change its size :) do I have to drop the animation completely if the menu is resizable?

```js
function openMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "500px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "500px";
}

function closeMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

openMenu();
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.middle {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.menu {
  height: calc(100% - 110px);
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
  resize: horizontal;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}



/* ----- MENU CONTENT ----- */

.closebtn {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}

.menuContent {
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Rouge Script', cursive;font-family: 'Princess Sofia', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openMenu()">LOGO IMAGE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div id="menu" class="menu">
                <div class="menuContent">
                    <h1>Title h1</h1>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeMenu()">&times;</a>
                    
                    <h2>Title h2 - 1</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 2</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 3</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 4</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 5</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                    <h2>Title h2 - 6</h2>
                    <p>Hello</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openMenu()">&#9776; menu</span>
                <div id="mapBody"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bit of javascript code and tweak some design of the project to make the bar a bit easy to resize.

code in HTML

```js
var i = 0;
var dragging = false;
   $('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       
       dragging = true;
       var main = $('#main');
       var ghostbar = $('<div>',
                        {id:'ghostbar',
                         css: {
                                height: main.outerHeight(),
                                top: main.offset().top,
                                left: main.offset().left
                               }
                        }).appendTo('body');
       
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          ghostbar.css("left",e.pageX+2);
       });
    });

   $(document).mouseup(function(e){
       if (dragging) 
       {
           $('#sidebar').css("width",e.pageX+2);
           $('#main').css("left",e.pageX+2);
           $('#ghostbar').remove();
           $(document).unbind('mousemove');
           dragging = false;
       }
    });
```

```css
body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
#main{
   background-color: BurlyWood;
   float: right;
   position: absolute;
   height:200px;
   right: 0;
   left:200px;
   margin-top:10px;
    
}
#sidebar{
   background-color: IndianRed;
    
   margin-top:10px;
   width:200px;
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   height:200px;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}

#dragbar{
   background-color:black;
   height:100%;
   float: right;
   width: 3px;
   cursor: col-resize;
}
#ghostbar{
    width:3px;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    position:absolute;
    cursor: col-resize;
    z-index:999}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
     <span id="position"></span>
    <div id="dragbar"></div>
    sidebar
</div>
<div id="main">
    main
</div>
```

code in css for the HTML :

```
 body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
#main{
   background-color: BurlyWood;
   float: right;
   position: absolute;
   height:200px;
   right: 0;
   left:200px;
   margin-top:10px;
    
}
#sidebar{
   background-color: IndianRed;
    
   margin-top:10px;
   width:200px;
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   height:200px;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}

#dragbar{
   background-color:black;
   height:100%;
   float: right;
   width: 3px;
   cursor: col-resize;
}
#ghostbar{
    width:3px;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    position:absolute;
    cursor: col-resize;
    z-index:999}
```

Javascript :

```
var i = 0;
var dragging = false;
   $('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       
       dragging = true;
       var main = $('#main');
       var ghostbar = $('<div>',
                        {id:'ghostbar',
                         css: {
                                height: main.outerHeight(),
                                top: main.offset().top,
                                left: main.offset().left
                               }
                        }).appendTo('body');
       
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          ghostbar.css("left",e.pageX+2);
       });
    });

   $(document).mouseup(function(e){
       if (dragging) 
       {
           $('#sidebar').css("width",e.pageX+2);
           $('#main').css("left",e.pageX+2);
           $('#ghostbar').remove();
           $(document).unbind('mousemove');
           dragging = false;
       }
    });
```

Hope this gives an idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Could you make it a snippet, please?

Comment: Hi, thanks, however the code in the snippet does not seem to work? I get that you're catching the mouse clicks and updating sidebar width accordingly but I'm wondering what visual effects this creates?

Comment: this creates a sliding visual effect where it can be slided from left to right and vice versa. Theres no error in code howsoever, this is related to SO